# download a file, validate the download, attempt again if not downloaded

Tags: python, loops

Here is what I want to do:

1. Using Python 3 and Selenium, click a link to download a file (but it could be a file downloaded by any method).
2. Check every 50 milliseconds to make sure the file exists. Download the file again if it doesn't exist after 5 seconds.
3. If I get the file, continue the script.
4. If I don't get the file, try up to 3 times total to get the file. If I still don't get the file after 3 attempts, exit the script.

Here's the code that just isn't working for me:

```
loop_1 = 0
while loop_1 < 3:

##### download the file

    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Search Results').click()

    ##### check the existence of the downloaded file; 
    ##### if not there within 5 seconds, download the file again

    loop_2 = 0
    while loop_2 < 100:
        f_exists = os.path.isfile('/Users/jeff/downloaded.csv')
        if f_exists != True:
            print(loop_2, 'file DOES NOT exist')
            loop_2 = loop_2 + 1
            time.sleep(.05)
        if f_exists == True:
            print(loop_1, 'file exists')
            break
    loop_1 = loop_1 + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using while loop when for looks much cleaner ?

```
for i in range(0,3):
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Search Results').click()
    for j in range(0,101):
        f_exists = os.path.isfile('/Users/jeff/downloaded.csv')
        if not f_exists:
            print(j, 'file DOES NOT exist')
            time.sleep(.05)
        else:
            print(i, 'file exists')
            return
```

Comment: That does look much cleaner. Thansk! Only issue is that the file downloads 3 times even though I'm getting printed out "file exists". It should exit the loop completely and continue the script as soon as the file downloads and exists. Any help there?

Comment: @JeffF Ah, the problem is that the second break -- breaks out of immediate outer loop. I've replaced it with return which exits the outermost loop. The code above should work fine now.

Comment: Seems like it's really close but I get this error: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: yeah, you're supposed to put that block inside a function and call that function.

Comment: You beat me to it. I finally figured that out. Thank you so much! Works perfect!